# How to show GeoJson javascript data as layer in Google Maps in iOS swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-maps, geojson

I have requirement that is, I have to show GeoJson data (java script file) as a layer in Google maps either using Native or Web view. I have checked few forums, as per they said, it is possible only for Android to load java script for loading data layer in Google maps.

So, my requirement is, I want to show some java script which contains geojson data as layer and then after that, I have to draw a route or path from start point to end point in map(like user started walking from 1 place to other place around 1 to 10 kms like footsteps).

I seen in Google maps forum, only Android and Web possible this kind requirement.

And I have checked MapBox library too, I am not sure whether it will help to my requirement. But, my preference is Google Maps.

Anyone can suggest me how to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly want. You want to add layers and when you select one layer you will get a geojson? This geojson should draw on map from 1 place to other?

Comment: I am looking for to show GeoJson data file as layer in google maps, its like java script file.

Comment: I‘m sorry, I‘m still confused. Where do you get the javascript file and why javascript? At the end you will have a geojson? Do you have an example of that? I’m quite sure that you can add marker to GoogleMaps as a kind of point of interest. They are called layers. In my world geojsons are often use to show areas like an overlay. So please be more specific and I‘m quite sure that I can help you

Comment: @kuzdu I really appreciate your response, actually I have two requirements 1. I have geojson file which is format of java script, I have to load this file to show layer in maps 2. I have to draw a path for user foot steps (suppose from user location, he starts walking to some place in any direction, from starting point to ending point I have to draw a path it may be circle or curve, etc directional. clear? this is my requirement. So, now tell me how can I achieve this?

Comment: The official documentation explains how to use GeoJSON in Google Maps SDK for iOS: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/kml-geojson

Comment: I'm confused about the layer term. In that youtube video from google https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AE-Al5mNu44 layers are  annotations with a group. 
If you like to draw an area with geojson use the docu. If you need grouped annotations you should create your own GMSMarker.
For the connection from point to point you have to draw a polyline. If you need footstep images get the coordinates from a polyline and set GMSMarkers with a footstep icon.

Comment: instead of annotations I have to show it as layer like some lines.

Comment: Maybe you draw a wireframe or something to show me what you exactly need. I think the terms a completely mixed up.